# как из адаптера вывести число в MainActivity

Tags: java, android, sqlite, recyclerview

цель:вывести сумму
в MainActivity есть RecycleView и TextView "корзина"
в item списка есть строка "цена" и кнопка "купить"

при нажатий на кнопку "купить" я вывожу сумму в TextView но не могу сложить с другой

это адаптер

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.Holder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Model> arrayList;
    private TextView ad;

    public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model> arrayList, TextView ad) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.ad = ad;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        return new Holder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Holder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {

            Model model = arrayList.get(position);

            String id = model.getId();
            String name = model.getName();
            String phone = model.getPhone();



            holder.name.setText(name);
            holder.phone1.setText(phone);


            holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {



                   ad.setText(phone+ 1);

                }
            });

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    editDialog(position,
                            id,
                            name,
                            phone);
                }
            });


    }


    private void editDialog(int position, String id, String name, String phone) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context , EditRecordActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("ID", id);
        intent.putExtra("NAME", name);
        intent.putExtra("PHONE", phone);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }


    public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        TextView name, phone1;
        Button button;
        TextView  ad;


        public Holder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            ad = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_price);
            button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_bay);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            phone1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        }
    }
}
```

это класс для бд SQLite

````
```   public class Constants {
//Создаем переменные для базы данных
public static final String DB_NAME = "PERSON_INFO";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "PERSON_INFO_TABLE";

public static final String C_ID = "ID";
public static final String C_NAME = "NAME";
public static final String C_PHONE = "PHONE";



public static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
        + C_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        + C_NAME + " TEXT,"
        + C_PHONE + " TEXT"
        + ");";
````

} ```

это MainActivity

```
    FloatingActionButton fab;
    ActionBar actionBar;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    //вывод суммы
    TextView ad;
    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.Agent);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        ad=findViewById(R.id.txt_price);

        //добавление и установка адаптера
        showRecord();


        fab = findViewById(R.id.addFabButton);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddRecordActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });



    }
    //добавление и установка адаптера
    private void showRecord() {
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(MainActivity.this, databaseHelper.getAllData(), ad);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        showRecord();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == event.KEYCODE_BACK){
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

[image: main]

Comment: Не понятно что и с чем складывать надо. Сфокусируйте вопрос на проблеме, не надо вываливать все от БД до UI. Если вы можете записать число куда надо, непонятно что вам мешает прочесть что там уже записано, сложить с новым значением и записать результат.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте интерфейс:

```
interface NumberSender {
    fun onNumberSent(count:Int)
}
```

Это интерфейс пусть реализует Ваша активити:

```
class MainActivity : AppActivity, NumberSender {
```

В адаптер передайте эту активити в виде интерфейса

```
Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model> arrayList, TextView ad, **NumberSender sender** )
```

и в нужном месте адаптера вызовите метод:

```
sender.onNumberSent(12312)
```

В адаптере можете дергать метод от активити и передавать туда все что угодно... если надо можно передать в ViewHolder интерфейс и там дергать этот метод... TextView в адаптер передавать не надо, им должна управлять активити, а не адаптер другого компонента....

П.С: немного Котлина, но главное, думаю, что суть понятна